# Why does inverting a bool result from a function param give a compiler error in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm just starting to learn swift, but this makes no sense to me. This code:

```
func myFlipper(f: Int -> Bool, num:Int) {
    return !f(num)
}
```

Results in a compiler error "Cannot invoke '!' with an argument of type 'Bool'".

From Apple's swift doc "The logical NOT operator (!a) inverts a Boolean value so that true becomes false, and false becomes true." [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-XID_129)

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function has void type and you are returning Bool. If you want to return Bool write it as,

```
func myFlipper(f: Int -> Bool, num:Int) -> Bool{
   return !f(num)
}
```

Otherwise dont return anything and it does not give any warning.

Comment: Swift lesson #1 should be that the error you get and the actual problem are sometimes quite different...

Comment: Thanks, yes that solved it. But the error message is still not only misleading, it's non-sensical. :) @AlexWayne Thanks for the tip, that's good to know

Comment: Yes: you should absolutely [report this](https://bugreport.apple.com/) as an issue in Swift so that Apple can fix it.